# Wygwam Causing 404 Error on Update

Tags: ee2, pixelandtonic, wygwam

Very confusing error: When the Wygwam field is edited with anything beyond one paragraph - or anything else such as an email link is added - the EE "Udpate" button causes a 404 error page. This happens both with a new entry or if the entry is being updated.

This error only started happening when I transitioned the site to a new server so maybe there are some Wygwam paths I need to update? JS files not loading? HTACCESS issues? I am pretty sure Wygwam is causing the entire entry to error because if I leave it blank there is no error.

This problem is, of course, making it impossible to edit content since Wygwam is ideal for body text fields. Please advise?

-Brandon

Comment: The Wygwam field behavior is volatile: sometimes a new line of text can be added and there are no errors. Other times, no new line can be added. It's haphazard and I can't figure out when exactly there's an error or what is triggering it.

Comment: Brandon, have you checked your browser's debug console when doing these actions?  There may be errors htere that will help.  Also - what version of EE and Wygwam are you on?

Comment: This sounds like it could be a mod_security error on the server. You could try posting the same content in a normal textarea field and see if it still happens. If it does you could contact the host to see if it's related to mod_security.

Comment: Try asking your host to disable 'mod_security', this often fixes many problems for us.